# Count the occurrence of a value among multiple associative arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

What is the most optimal way to count the occurrence of a value among many associative arrays. For instance, we have

```
var array1 = {
  firstname: 'john',
  lastname: 'bob'
};
var array2 = {
  firstname: 'sara',
 lastname: 'johnson'
};
var array 3 = {
  firstname: 'john',
  lastname: 'paul'
};
```

how would I in this case count the number of times "john" occurs as a first name? (return value should be 2)

Comment: That's your basic looping through the arrays then check `if (firstnam =="john")` increment the counter you have defined  and there

Comment: The accepted answer is the worst approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a count use the function `reduce`, you don't need to create additional arrays (using the function `filter`) for doing that.

```js
var array1 = {firstname: 'john',lastname: 'bob'},
    array2 = {firstname: 'sara',lastname: 'johnson'},
    array3 = {firstname: 'john',lastname: 'paul'},
    count = [array1, array2, array3].reduce((a, c) => (a + (Object.keys(c).findIndex(k => k === 'firstname' && c[k] === 'john') > -1)), 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them into a single larger array, `filter` it by the `john` name, and then check its length:

```js
const array1 = {
  firstname: 'john',
  lastname: 'bob'
};
const array2 = {
  firstname: 'sara',
  lastname: 'johnson'
};
const array3 = {
  firstname: 'john',
  lastname: 'paul'
};
const input = [array1, array2, array3];
const johnCount = input.filter(({ firstname }) => firstname === 'john').length;
console.log(johnCount);
```

Comment: This is the worst approach.  Creating a new array is really unnecessary.

Comment: Generally, when `filter` is followed by `length`, it should have probably been `reduce`.

Comment: @Ele Why not? It's not like referencing already-existing objects is an array is an expensive operation - and you're doing the same thing, merging the objects into an array and then iterating over it. Clearly organizing the data before processing it shouldn't be something to be ashamed of. (though granted, `reduce` would be more elegant)

Comment: Yes, I’m putting within an array.  Your approach is doing a further step creating a new array using the function filter.